# R solution to max product in matrix for four adjacent numbers (Euler 11)

Tags: programming-challenge, matrix, r

## Background

This is solution to [Problem 11](https://projecteuler.net/problem=11) on Project Euler that is concerned with finding *largest product of four adjacent numbers* in the provided grid.

Other than solving the problem I was also interested in creating a search function that would have a more generic character and could search across any number of adjacent numbers.

### Provided Grid

*Read as `11grid.txt` in the provided code.*

```
08 02 22 97 38 15 00 40 00 75 04 05 07 78 52 12 50 77 91 08
49 49 99 40 17 81 18 57 60 87 17 40 98 43 69 48 04 56 62 00
81 49 31 73 55 79 14 29 93 71 40 67 53 88 30 03 49 13 36 65
52 70 95 23 04 60 11 42 69 24 68 56 01 32 56 71 37 02 36 91
22 31 16 71 51 67 63 89 41 92 36 54 22 40 40 28 66 33 13 80
24 47 32 60 99 03 45 02 44 75 33 53 78 36 84 20 35 17 12 50
32 98 81 28 64 23 67 10 26 38 40 67 59 54 70 66 18 38 64 70
67 26 20 68 02 62 12 20 95 63 94 39 63 08 40 91 66 49 94 21
24 55 58 05 66 73 99 26 97 17 78 78 96 83 14 88 34 89 63 72
21 36 23 09 75 00 76 44 20 45 35 14 00 61 33 97 34 31 33 95
78 17 53 28 22 75 31 67 15 94 03 80 04 62 16 14 09 53 56 92
16 39 05 42 96 35 31 47 55 58 88 24 00 17 54 24 36 29 85 57
86 56 00 48 35 71 89 07 05 44 44 37 44 60 21 58 51 54 17 58
19 80 81 68 05 94 47 69 28 73 92 13 86 52 17 77 04 89 55 40
04 52 08 83 97 35 99 16 07 97 57 32 16 26 26 79 33 27 98 66
88 36 68 87 57 62 20 72 03 46 33 67 46 55 12 32 63 93 53 69
04 42 16 73 38 25 39 11 24 94 72 18 08 46 29 32 40 62 76 36
20 69 36 41 72 30 23 88 34 62 99 69 82 67 59 85 74 04 36 16
20 73 35 29 78 31 90 01 74 31 49 71 48 86 81 16 23 57 05 54
01 70 54 71 83 51 54 69 16 92 33 48 61 43 52 01 89 19 67 48
```

## Solution

### Notes

The solution:

1. Gets addresses of all cells in the matrix
2. From each address creates a list of neighbours in each direction (North, South, ...)
3. Product is calculated on each of the sets
4. Max product is returned

### Code

```
# Notes -------------------------------------------------------------------

# Problem 11

# Data --------------------------------------------------------------------

# Read provided matrix
M <-
    matrix(
        data = scan("./problems/11/11grid.txt"),
        nrow = 20,
        ncol = 20
    )

# Support -----------------------------------------------------------------

# Pad matrix for the desired number of neighbhours
pad_matrix <- function(M, n = 4) {
    # Create a list of NAs to pad
    l <- lapply(X = 1:n, function(x) {
        NA
    })
    # Pad columns
    lc <- l
    lc[[1]] <- M
    Mcols <- do.call(what = cbind, args = lc)
    Mcols <- do.call(what = cbind, args = {
        # Pad other side
        lc[[1]] <- Mcols
        rev(lc)
    })
    # Pad rows
    lr <- l
    lr[[1]] <- Mcols
    Mcols_rows <- do.call(what = rbind, args = lr)
    Mcols_rows <- do.call(what = rbind, args = {
        # Pad other side
        lr[[1]] <- Mcols
        rev(lr)
    })
    Mcols_rows
}


# Search ------------------------------------------------------------------

search_product <- function(M = M, n = 4) {
    addresses <- expand.grid(x = sequence(nrow(M)),
                             y = sequence(ncol(M)))
    n_search <- n - 1

    # Create padded matrx
    M_pad <- pad_matrix(M = M, n = n)


    neighbhours_res <- apply(
        X = addresses,
        MARGIN = 1,
        FUN = function(M_addr) {
            tryCatch(
                expr = list(
                    North = M_pad[M_addr["x"]:(M_addr["x"] - n_search), M_addr["y"]],
                    North_East = c(M_pad[M_addr["x"], M_addr["y"]], sapply(
                        X = 1:n_search,
                        FUN = function(i) {
                            M_pad[M_addr["x"] - i,
                                  M_addr["y"] + i]
                        }
                    )),
                    East = M_pad[M_addr["x"], M_addr["y"]:(M_addr["y"] + n_search)],
                    South_East = c(M_pad[M_addr["x"], M_addr["y"]], sapply(
                        X = 1:n_search,
                        FUN = function(i) {
                            M_pad[M_addr["x"] + i,
                                  M_addr["y"] + i]
                        }
                    )),
                    South = M_pad[M_addr["x"]:(M_addr["x"] + n_search), M_addr["y"]],
                    South_West = c(M_pad[M_addr["x"], M_addr["y"]], sapply(
                        X = 1:n_search,
                        FUN = function(i) {
                            M_pad[M_addr["x"] + i,
                                  M_addr["y"] - i]
                        }
                    )),
                    West = M_pad[M_addr["x"], M_addr["y"]:(M_addr["y"] - n_search)],
                    North_West = c(M_pad[M_addr["x"], M_addr["y"]], sapply(
                        X = 1:n_search,
                        FUN = function(i) {
                            M_pad[M_addr["x"] - i,
                                  M_addr["y"] - i]
                        }
                    ))
                ),
                error = function(e) {
                    NA
                }
            )
        }
    )
    products <-
        rapply(object = neighbhours_res,
               f = prod,
               classes = "numeric")
    # Keep max only
    max(products, na.rm = TRUE)
}
res <- search_product(M = M, n = 4)
res
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When working with matrices in R, you can often do an operation with a single command if you are clever about how that is structured. Take padding a matrix with `npad` missing values as an example. Your current code does this by first padding the columns and then padding the rows. However, you could define a correct-sized matrix with all missing values to start, and then store the original matrix at the correct location within the new matrix:

```
pad_matrix2 <- function(M, npad) {
  padded <- matrix(NA, nrow(M)+2*npad, ncol(M)+2*npad)
  padded[seq(npad+1, nrow(M)+npad),seq(npad+1, ncol(M)+npad)] <- M
  padded
}
```

This is much more compact code and will also be more efficient.

In terms of the `search_product` function, you have a lot of repeated code that does the same thing for a particular direction. You could avoid that by looping through a set of directions that you want to search:

```
search_product2 <- function(M, n=4) {
  npad <- n-1
  M_pad <- pad_matrix2(M, npad)
  directions <- rbind(c(1, 0), c(0, 1), c(1, 1), c(1, -1))
  all.pos <- expand.grid(r=seq(npad+1, nrow(M)+npad),
                         c=seq(npad+1, ncol(M)+npad))
  max(apply(directions, 1, function(direction) {
    max(Reduce("*", lapply(seq(0, n-1), function(dist) {
      M_pad[cbind(all.pos$r+dist*direction[1],
                  all.pos$c+dist*direction[2])]
    })), na.rm=TRUE)
  }))
}
search_product2(M, 4) == search_product(M, 4)
# [1] TRUE
```